# Weird behavior in meteor when forming a query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Till now, I had believe that the order of keys in query does not matter until I encountered the following case :

Let's say there's a collection with documents and you need to find just one that belongs to a certain group. The following `query` will fail to fetch document with an `_id` `pFkpqenxxbiFFtzrd`. Instead, it will fetch `2SYzj829FKnezgX3b`

```
db.getCollection('Facilities').findOne({_id: "pFkpqenxxbiFFtzrd", _id: {$in: [ '2SYzj829FKnezgX3b', 'pFkpqenxxbiFFtzrd', 'Znsbs5Rzr6DopZmro' ]}})
```

While this one will do it :

```
db.getCollection('Facilities').findOne({_id: {$in: [ '2SYzj829FKnezgX3b', 'pFkpqenxxbiFFtzrd', 'Znsbs5Rzr6DopZmro' ]}, _id: "pFkpqenxxbiFFtzrd"})
```

The question is why?

Comment: Duplicate property names are not allowed, use a single `$in` for all IDs or `$or` instead.

Comment: Hardly weird, but certainly invalid and it's nothing to do with MongoDB anyway but basic rules of JavaScript objects. Cannot have the same key.

Comment: What you are trying to do would actually be an `$and`, but it does not really make sense and should be an `$or`, but if you mean that then simply add the item to the `$in`. You simply cannot have different conditions on the same key because JavaScript objects don't allow that. That's what the "array" operators are actually for.